# Drupal form submission to a 3rd party website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

I'm building a form in Drupal that needs to submit to a 3rd party website. Within the form API it seems like this is not really possible as you register form submission handlers to do all of the processing. I need to have the form method to to POST and it needs to be submitted to this website as it is a 3rd party hosted ordering system. Has anyone run into a similar situation? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `#action` attribute on the form array:

```
$form['#action'] = 'http://example.com';
```